# Macro to delimit the XML while importing the text that contains XML tags

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a macro to delimit the XML while importing the text that contains XML tags so as to preserve the format while uploading the test cases to Rally through Excel.

For example, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Any generic solution is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) as in:

```
>> s = "<tag> text </tag>"
>> WScript.Echo "<div>" & Replace(Replace(s, "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&gt;") & "</div>"
>>
<div>&lt;tag&gt; text &lt;/tag&gt;</div>
```